# IntelliJ fails to resolve symbols (imports) provided by maven (in pom.xml)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss

I have a JEE project and I use maven to build it. In the pom.xml, I specify certain dependencies, e.g. for org.jboss.ejb3 or org.jboss.logging.

Building the application works, both inside/ with the IDE as well as manually invoking "mvn clean install" from the cmd. My issue now is that all imports from the dependencies included in the pom.xml are marked as "cannot be resolved" which results in correct code being marked as incorrect as well as auto-completion not working. I have tried re-importing the project but that has not yielded anything at all.

Also, I have already searched the internet (including Stackoverflow) but none of the answers found were able to help me fix it.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I'm not. Normal LAN connection in my home

Comment: Did you check the Maven Settings XML file?

Comment: How has the re-import of the project done? Have you tried importing this as a maven project in the IDE by right clicking on the pom.xml and selecting "add as a maven project"?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what errors you are seeing I am going to assume that your issue is with eclipse project properties (build path, src directory specification, output classes directory, etc).

You tagged m2eclipse plugin, so you should be able to right click on your project in eclipse select maven->update project configuration. If you do not see that option under maven then you should first see an option called maven->enable dependency management. Click that first and then you should be able to see update project configuration option.

If this does not fix it, then open your project directory containing the pom.xml file in command prompt and run mvn eclipse:eclipse.

One of the above should resolve those pesky error messages provided that your maven build itself is successful.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ